# Azure: Publish a separated web API project in the same domain to another web app

Tags: azure

When I have an ASP.NET web app with some API controllers that has a route `/api` for example, I can publish the app to Azure Web App and use the api by accessing `someproject.azurewebsites.net/api/controller`.

However, when I separate a web API part from the web app project, I have to publish the web API project to new domain like `someapiproject.azurewebsites.net`. I want to integrate the web API project to the web app just as I did with one combined project.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine multiple APIs, you should take a look at [Azure API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/). 
I doubt that you can publish multiple APIs into a single Web API since both requires a startup where you configure the host.

What you can do to cleanup your code is to *outsource* the controller into different assemblies and configure them in the middleware. [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1109388/Extending-MVC-Controllers-from-External-Assemblies) is an example.

Comment: It makes sense that we'll have a problem in Startup.cs. Could you give me some example or tutorial about using middleware to handle outsourced class library for API?

Comment: Sure, I added a link.

Answer (score 0):

Martin Brandl's answer is spot on. But if you want to go the poor man's route, you can create a reverse proxy from your ASP.NET Web App and map app traffic from someproject.azurewebsites.net/apiV2 to someapiproject.azurewebsites.net. This is not a HTTP 30x redirect - the URL will not change for users hitting your /apiV2. I've personally used this approach because the Azure API Management service can get a little pricey. If you don't need the sexy features like throttling, this can be a good way to go.